# One of my `{{link-to}}` helpers is triggering a page reload. How can i figure out what is causing that page to reload completely?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The link is supposed to send me back to the index page `/` from the `/:id` path. When I go back with the browser back button it does not reload the page and all is fine. The link it produces looks fine to me `href="/"` In other parts of the app for example going back to the index from `/new` the same `{{link-to}}` helper works fine.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('conversations', {path: '/'}, function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('conversation', {path: '/:conversation_id'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

Back Button in conversation template:

```
{{#link-to 'conversations'}}
```

Conversation Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            conversation: this.store.find('conversation', params.conversation_id),
            messages: this.store.find('message')
        });
    }

});
```

Conversations Index Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('conversation');
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in JS Bin?

Comment: Having a hard time putting together the JSBin: Can't even get the dynamic URL to work in the bin: http://jsbin.com/tuvedu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You should at least demonstrate your issue by adding some code to your question for clarification.

Comment: added some code to my question

Comment: Can you post your ConversationsRoute?

Comment: Added it the conversations index route the conversations route is generated.

Comment: I am using ember-cli and just upgraded to ember 1.13.2. All links work fine when building with --environment=development, but when building with --environment=production I get the same behavior on some links.

Comment: I would love to know a method for debugging these kinds of things.

Comment: I see an error in the console popping up but because of the reload I can not read what it says..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution to be able to find the problem:

In Chrome I activated "Preserve log upon navigation" to be able to see the Error. In the Settings of the Chrome Developer Tools.

Then I removed the problem which in my case was very simple by following the error:
 had no action handler for: back